# SugarCRM 6.5.20 add field not working

Tags: php, sugarcrm

I have installed `SugarCRM 6.5.20` community version I want to add filed in Accounts module when i click on add field in accounts module the following error i am getting

> **Warning: Creating default object from empty value in /opt/lampp/htdocs/SugarCRM/modules/ModuleBuilder/views/view.modulefield.php
>   on line 151 {"east":{"title":"Edit Field","crumb":"","content":"
>   </div>\n\n****

Can any one help me out to fix this.Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is a Bug/issue with SugarCRM itself. Try disabling PHP's Display Errors setting ([display_errors](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors)).

Answer (score 0):

Please check for proper permission has been set as per standard:

https://support.sugarcrm.com/04_Knowledge_Base/02Administration/100Install/Required_File_System_Permissions_on_Linux/